# How do I duplicate bones 90° and copy rotation?

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

I have a set of bones with an Inverse Kinematic constraint. I need to be able to duplicate this set up so that I have four sets in total, each rotated 90° about the center.

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but when I do this, the bones don't rotate on their local y-axes.

[image]

This means that when I try to use a Copy Rotation constraint, Local to Local, it doesn't work properly, because each individual bone hasn't been rotated 90° when the whole set did.

[image]

Here is the file in case it helps:
[image]